# Disable component when fetching data in dropdown options

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a dropdown component and i want to disable whole component when option data fetching. When data comes component should be enabled.

```
const isTypeView = type === 'view';

 <SearchableDropdown
        {...register('expectedSkillsIds')}
        disabled={isTypeView}
        errors={errors}
        isMulti
        isRequired
        onChange={(value) =>
          handleDropdownChange('expectedSkillsIds', [
            ...(expectedSkillsIds || []),
            ...value,
          ] as any)
        }
        options={
          skillsData?.skills
            .filter(
              (skill) =>
                (expectedSkillsIds || []).findIndex(
                  (selectedSkillId) => selectedSkillId === skill.id,
                ) === -1,
            )
            .map((skill) => ({ value: skill.id, label: skill.name })) || []
        }
        placeholder={t('forms:placeholders.searchOrSelect')}
      />
```

Comment: `disabled={isTypeView || !skillsData}` should work

Comment: set a variable when loading data